# Why is rails adding characters before 'text' in <script type="text/javascript">?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have embedded javascript code in a html.erb file like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        hsoub_adplace = 123456789;
        hsoub_adplace_size = '728x90';
    //-->
</script>
<script src="http://ads2.hsoub.com/show.js" type="text/javascript>
</script>
```

When I check the source code of the page on the browser it always shows added characters like

```
<script type="dc97de70b98b8236cb59f02a-text/javascript">
    <!--
        hsoub_adplace = 1701244334223565;
        hsoub_adplace_size = '728x90';
    //-->
</script>
<script src="http://ads2.hsoub.com/show.js" type="dc97de70b98b8236cb59f02a-text/javascript">
</script>
```

Rails has added `dc97de70b98b8236cb59f02a` before `text` Is this normal? Why does it happen with Rails?

gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.2'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# added because of hartl tutorial
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'

# rtl for arabic
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails-rtl', '~> 2.3'

# detect visitor location
gem 'geoip', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]

  # added because of hartl tutorial
  gem 'guard',                    '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '~> 2.4.4'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '~> 1.1.14'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0.2'
  gem 'rubocop'
  # gem for ruby code auto completion
  gem 'solargraph'
  # gem for better formatting ruby code, I think ruboco does this better
  # to use this one, we should run format ruby file
  gem 'rufo'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # added because of hartl tutorial
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>



    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="4A7AAC90C0A65CAB38069149C2679842" />
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon16x16.ico' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon16x16.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon', :type => 'image/png' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo' %>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#D83434">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="app/assets/favicon16x16.png">


  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5XMWF2S');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-109565723-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-109565723-1');
    </script>


    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  </head>



  <body>
    <body>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5XMWF2S"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container", dir= "rtl">
      <p class="lead">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class= "alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      </p>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is Rails, and not some other library you have plugged in? Can you confirm this happens in a bare rails application with nothing else installed?

Comment: It is rails. I develop on my windows machine (bad i know). and use doku on digital ocean to deploy..etc I don't think there is any library plugged in.

Comment: What I meant was: Are you sure Rails is at fault? I'm not suggesting you're not using rails. 

Can you add your Gemfile to the issue, so we can see if any other libraries may interfere? And perhaps your application.erb file as well.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my question to show gem and application files content. Thanks

Comment: I suspect that it is turbolinks that's doing this, in order to cache the scripts.